# Replace DataTemplate in custom control

Tags: wpf

I have an assembly `MyAssembly` with a custom-made `WPF` control `MyControl`. This control displays different types of objects, and for this type-specific data templates are used:

```
<MyControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyFirstType}">
     ...
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MySecondType}">
     ...
  </DataTemplate>
</MyControl.Resources>
```

---

**Q:**
How can I allow the programmer to define new data templates that *replace* the UI created by `MyControl`? What is the common design principle here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ItemTemplateSelector /ContentTemplateSelector. [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    public class TaskListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
        {
           //Set Template based on conditions
            Task taskitem = item as Task;

            if (taskitem.Priority == 1)
                return
                    element.FindResource("importantTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else 
                return
                    element.FindResource("myTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}


<Window.Resources>

<local:TaskListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>

</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}"
     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: Using a DataTemplateSelector surely is a good technique, but it doesn't answer my question. I need an elegant way of re-assigning data templates from the outside. Or, hmm... are you saying that using resources is the key?